# gradient with respect to weights of negative log likelihood

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, gradient-descent, log-likelihood

I am trying to derive the gradient of the negative log likelihood function with respect to the weights, $w$.

The solution is [here](https://piazza-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/h61o5linlbb1v0/h8exwp8dmm44ok/classificationV6.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEDNRLJ4AZKBW6HA&Expires=1485650876&Signature=Rd4BqBgb4hPwWUjxAyxJNfPhklU%3D) (at the bottom of page 7).

However, I keep arriving at a solution of

$$\ - \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x_i e^{w^Tx_i}(2y_i-1)}{e^{w^Tx_i} + 1}$$

Is there a step-by-step guide of how this is done? I can't figure out how they arrived at that solution.